# progress dialog not showing when declared, initialized and called

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I am making a sign in activity and i want it to show the progress dialog when the sign in button is pressed I declared, initialized, and called it but it's not showing.
But when I called the progress dialog within the on create it showed up

This is my code below:

```
public class Login extends Activity {
private EditText username, password;
private Button login;
private Button signup;
String txtUsername, txtPassword, loggedin;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;
String titleId = "Logging in";
int id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);

    // Login button listener
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            showProgress();
            // Retrieve text from the EditText
            txtUsername = username.getText().toString();
            txtPassword = password.getText().toString();

            if (txtUsername.isEmpty() && txtPassword.isEmpty()) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Username And Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            } else {
                User user = db.getUser(txtUsername, txtPassword);
                id = user.getId();

                if (txtUsername.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getUsername())
                        && txtPassword.equals(user.getPassword())) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,
                            AdministratorPage.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username", "username");
                    intent.putExtra("id", "id");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Successfully Logged In as "
                                    + user.getUsername(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Usename Or Password Incorrect",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    username.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                }
            }
        }

    });

    // Sign up button listener
    signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            showProgress();
            // Retrieve text from the EditText
            txtUsername = username.getText().toString();
            txtPassword = password.getText().toString();

            if (txtUsername.isEmpty() && txtPassword.isEmpty()) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Enter Username And Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            } else {

                // Inserting Contacts
                Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                db.addUser(new User(txtUsername, txtPassword, "Y"));

                // Reading all contacts
                Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
                List<User> users = db.getAllUsers();

                for (User cn : users) {
                    String log = "Id: " + cn.getId() + " ,Name: "
                            + cn.getUsername() + " ,Password: "
                            + cn.getPassword();
                    // Writing Contacts to log
                    Log.d("Name: ", log);
                }
                mProgress.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,
                        AdministratorPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }

    });

}

public void showProgress() {
    // Initialize the Progress Dialog
    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
    mProgress.setTitle(titleId);
    mProgress.setMessage("Logging In Please Wait...");

    mProgress.show();
}
```

Comment: I don´t know what you are expecting but on every case in your if/else structure, you are dismiss the dialog.....so I guess the dialog shows up some milliseconds but gets dismissed directly..

Comment: I' am testing it on an emulator so usually it shows up and I have written recently a similar activity with the same method for a progress dialog and it was showing but not here is this activity

Answer (score 1):

All your code is running synchronously and you are dismissing the progress dialog before the system had a chance to actually show it.

You would have to put all your login stuff into an AsyncTask or similar, then the progress bar would be shown. Although in your case the AsyncTask would finish so quickly that you'd hardly notice the progress dialog. But if you'd check the username/password against a backend server, it would work with an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

If you simple want to use Progress Dialog you should write this code in a Veriable.

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
```

and in Singin ClickListener Write this code.

```
 dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Logging In", "Please wait...", true);
```

and Write this when you want to dismiss

```
dialog.dismiss();
```